# Zip folder first then allow user to download it

Tags: php, download, zip, rar

On my site I want to have a link that can zip a particular folder including its content then allow the user to download it. It will be use for downloading a bundled files.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 $files[] = base_url().'uploads/'.$names->file_name;
```

pass your files into this `$files[]` array.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();  
    $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
    $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);   
    foreach($files as $file)
    {      //echo $file; exit;
        $download_file = file_get_contents($file); 

        $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file); 


    }
    $zip->close();

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=project_files.zip');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    readfile($tmp_file);
```